# How to create caching/hot version of rx.Single?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, kotlin

The RxJava [v1.0.13](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v1.0.13) introduced new type of an Observable: **rx.Single**. It fits great the request-response model but lacks the standard side-effects introducing operators like doOnNext(). So, it's much harder to make multiple things happen as a result.

My idea was to replace doOnNext() with multiple subscriptions to the same Single instance. But this can cause the underlaying work to be done multiple times: once per every subscription.

Example rx.Single implementation:

```
private class WorkerSubscribe<SomeData>() : Single.OnSubscribe<SomeData> {
    override fun call(sub: SingleSubscriber<in SomeData>) {
        try {
            val result = fetchSomeData()
            sub.onSuccess(result)
        } catch(t: Throwable) {
            sub.onError(t)
        }
    }
}

val single = Single.create<SomeData>(WorkerSubscribe())
```

Usage:

```
single.subscribe({}, {})
single.subscribe({}, {})   // Data is fetched for the second time
```

Is it possible to create a instance of Single that will not fetchSomeData() multiple times even when single.subscribe() is called multiple times, but cache and return the same result?

Comment: Singles don't have doOnNext because they don't have an onNext in the first place. However, they have a doOnSuccess (because Singles have an onSuccess instead of onNext)

Answer (score 2):

You need [RxJava Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html): `BehaviorSubject` or `AsyncSubject`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a step back from using Single in the first place?

Comment: will you post a code example so that the solution doesn't need to be inferred?

Answer (score 2):

I just needed similar behavior and found some solution.

You can convert `Single` to `Observable` apply `cache()` and then convert it back to `Single`.

```
yourSingle.toObservable().cacheWithInitialCapacity(1).toSingle()
```

I use `cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)` instead of just `cache()` as an optimization - `Single` will never emit more than one item.

It is also good idea to provide `Transformer` implementation

```
public class SingleUtils {

    public static <T> Single.Transformer<T, T> cached() {
        return single -> single.toObservable()
            .cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)
            .toSingle();
    }
}
```

so you can use caching wherever you want by calling just

```
yourSingle.compose(SingleUtils.cached())
```

**Edit:**
Starting from rxJava 1.2.2 it has been added (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v1.2.2)

Implemented exactly this way
(https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4757)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [`cache()` operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#cache()).
It's supposed to cache the emissions from the `Observable` and reproduce them to the subsequent `Subscriber`s.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than answer because there is no definitive suggestion here other than "learn more about the cache operator"

Comment: `rx.Single` don't have `cache()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BehaviorSubject/ReplaySubject/AsyncSubject - and then call toSingle on it.

Comment: will you post a code example so that the solution doesn't need to be inferred?

Comment: None of those classes have a `toSingle()` method. Though, you can create a `Single.fromObservable()`; which a `Subject` inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

I made workaround, that I'm not happy with it but it works:

```
public class Network {
   private Object data;
   private Single<Object> dataSingle;

   public Single<Object> getData {
      if (data == null) {
         if (dataSingle == null) {
            dataSingle = Single.create(...)
             .doOnSuccess( data -> this.data = data;)
             .sibscribeOn(..);
         }
         return dataSingle;
      } else {
         return Single.just(data);
      }
   }
}
```